# IMAP + Ruby: How to search emails with multiple parameters with optional conditioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap, gmail-imap

I have code using which I am able to fetch emails from authenticated gmail account. At the moment there is a basic filter applied on it. But my requirement needs me to apply multiple filters like:

> [from: space@nasa.com]
>   AND [subject: life on mars]
>   OR [subject: life on venus]
>   AND [subject "not": life on earth]

Can any when suggest how I can apply filters like this on imap.search command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
imap.search(["FROM", "space@nasa.com", "SUBJECT", "life on mars", "OR", "life on venus", "NOT", "life on earth"])
```

Full documentation is available here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to perform the following query:

(FROM == "from-lookup-email@gmail.com" || TO == "to-lookup-email@gmail.com")

You can use the following seacrh command:

search_result = imap.search(["OR", "FROM", "from-lookup-email@gmail.com", "TO", "to-lookup-email@gmail.com"])